# How to define v7 appcompat dependency correctly?

Tags: android, ant, android-support-library, android-build

I'm trying to get an (inherited) Android project to build. I'm using [Ant & command line tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) (and IDEA).

In styles.xml, there are references that cannot be resolved such as:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

This is the original error I ran into:

```
[...]/res/values/styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item:
No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

I then noticed that `project.properties` has this appcompat reference which is broken on my (OS X) machine:

```
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=../../../../adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

I tried to fix that by making the reference relative to `${sdk.dir}`:

```
android.library.reference.1=${sdk.dir}/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

So now that path should be correct. But now when I run `ant debug`:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:573: 
  /opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat resolve to a 
  path with no project.properties file for project /Users/joka/devel/project/
```

So, any ideas? What's the simplest way to get this project built?

(Please note that Ecplise-specific advice won't be useful to me.)

*Edit*: The Android SDK installation looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the support package in `/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/`?

Comment: @Rajesh: Yes, I do. And more specifically `/opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/` seems to be installed just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, so I tried using a relative path and that fixed the problem for me. It looks like only relative paths work with android.library.reference. I did a quick search to verify this, and came across [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925747/how-do-you-set-the-android-library-absolute-path-in-ant-properties) which indicates that absolute paths will work with android.library.reference on Windows, but not on Unix or Mac.

Peace.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I got it working with `android.library.reference.1=../../../../../../../opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`
This also works in `local.properties`, which I think is a better place since the same path won't work for all developers.

Comment: (Additionally, for the Ant build to work, I needed to [generate build.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15718940/56285) for the appcompat project, using `/opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android update project -p /opt/android-sdk-macosx-r22.0.1/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`.)

Comment: I put a symlink in my project dir `root => /` and then I can have absolute paths be relative paths :)

Comment: @Jonik You should add your comment as an answer. It is exactly what worked for me.

Comment: @Code-Guru: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22055791/56285). Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 9):

[As Jay indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219119/56285), only *relative* paths will work on Unix/Mac.

For the Ant build to work, I also needed to [generate `build.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718940/56285) *for the appcompat project*, using the command `android update project -p <dir>`, in my case:

```
/opt/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android update project 
    -p /opt/android-sdk-macosx-r22.0.1/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
```

The exact config for me was:

`android.library.reference.1=../../../../../../../opt/android-sdk-macosx/extras/‌​android/support/v7/appcompat`

(This also works in `local.properties`, which I think is a better place since the same path won't work for all developers.)

---

I merely promoted my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209041/how-to-define-v7-appcompat-dependency-correctly#comment26718467_18219119) from 6 months ago into an answer as someone suggested.

By the way, now that I actually know something about Android development, I'd urge anyone who has the chance to ditch Ant and look into the [**new Gradle-based build system**](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) which is totally sweet in comprarison. It is CI-friendly and makes it easy to automate useful things (like using different package name and app icon for different build types). [Stack Overflow will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-gradle) when you run into problems.

Using the support libraries with Gradle, you'd skip all the above hassle and [simply do](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res):

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}
```

Comment: I also needed to change target=android-19 to target=android-21 in /opt/android-sdk-macosx-r22.0.1/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/project.properties as described by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml

Answer (score 0):

Your path seems to be wrong (you are missing the 'compatibility' part).
The v7-appcompat library is at

```
{sdkpath}/extras/android/compatibility/v7/appcompat
```

for me (SDK Tools version 22.0.5 on Max OS X 10.7.5)

Comment: Hmm, for me, `{sdkpath}/extras/android` contains only `support` and `m2repository` subdirectories. (And `{sdkpath}/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` seems to be exactly what I need.) If I'm missing some part of the SDK, how exactly should I install it? I'm also using Android SDK Tools 22.0.5.

Comment: Have you got the current version of the support libraries installed? (We are at version 18 at time of this comment) You can check by running the GUI of the SDK Update manager (execute the 'android' program in the tools subdirectory.) The support library is for me almost at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Yeah, [according to Android SDK Manager](http://i.stack.imgur.com/adUuX.png) I do have Android Support Library, rev 18 installed.

Comment: My apologies - apparently the SDK maintained an old path pattern for me (maybe to not break existing projects). When I un- and reinstalled it, it moved to your path without the 'compatibility' directory. So that does not seem to be the issue here... Sorry.