# Cannot resolve symbol 'android:TextApperance.Material' Android Studio

Tags: java, android, symbols, resolve

I have created a Google Maps Activity and I have a weird error: 'Cannot resolve symbol android:TextAppearance.Material' and also 100,000 more errors that start with'Cannot resolve symbol android:TextAppearance.Material' and the ThemeOverlay. I need some help because I am a total noob at this... (Yes, I tried the tools->android->sync project with gradle files and build->clean and rebuild project.) Thanks!

Edit: I also have the 'Cannot resolve symbol R' error, but I think that is because of this.

Comment: Your target SDK OK? This should be only for Android L (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [AppCompat v7 r21 returning error in values.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml)

There the solution pointed is (quoting):

"AppCompat v21 builds themes that require the new APIs provided in API 21 (Android 5.0). To compile your application with AppCompat, you must also compile against API 21. The recommended setup for compiling/building with API 21 is a compileSdkVersion of 21 and a buildToolsVersion of 21.0.1 (which is the highest at this time - you always want to use the latest build tools)."