# errors in values.xml while running AppCompat v7 r21 fire phone

Tags: android

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\amandeeg\AndroidStudioProjects\ImageFeeds\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.3\res\values-v11\values.xml
Error:(50, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
and many more like this...
```

Following is the build.gradle (module) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17"
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amandeeg.imagefeeds"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

and build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.amazon.device.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This gradle file is set up as suggested in setting up [dev env for fire phone plugin](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment)

I am new to android and not sure how to get around this problem. I cannot take the advice [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml) as firefly has a hard dependency on API 17.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: did you get rid of the issue?

Comment: @nadeemgc Yes i did. but unfortunately I do not remember what the fix was.

Answer (score 0):

You should be building with the newest tools. That means your appcompat, build tools and targetSdk should be as high as possible.

I believe changing to:

```
targetSdkVersion 21
```

would be enough. If your device is running API 17 it doesn't matter. Since you have minSdk at that.