# Application binary(.apk) is not generating when I import project

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I and my friend is working on an android application project. It was created in his computer with build target 19 and 8 as minimum sdk version. This Application has appcompat_v7 support library dependency & its working on his computer fine.

Now when I import that project in my computer, first time eclipse showed errors (cross sign) in java class files(under src folder) as they didn't find R (as R is not generated).

My appcompat_v7 is built with build target 21 ( if I build it with 19 it gives [Value-21 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml) ) which I have added with the project. So I thought may be that's why R is not generating as appcompat_v7 is built with build target 21 and the project is built with build target 19.

So I changed the project.properties of that project and set "target=android-21". And this time those error signs gone from the java class files. But when I build the project its not building.I mean binary / executable / *.apk file isn't generating. What can I do?

I am using eclipse Luna in Ubuntu 14.04. SDK 19 and SDK 21 both are installed in my computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building is only the first step to creating the APK.  When you run your application, the APK is generated in your build dir.  Simply run your project as an android application; you don't even need to have any emulator/device connected.

Comment: Thanks! Really surprised! I thought building creates the executable and running just installs it in the device / emulator.

Comment: Building compiles your source code, generates R, etc. but stops short of creating an APK.  Eclipse only assembles and signs an APK when you run it (and if it doesn't already have an up-to-date one in its build folder).