# android 2.3.3 do not recognize styles from supportlibrary in intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I'm trying to use action bar in android 2.3.3 .i use [this link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyaZEphsz44) to add support library in `intellij` . it does not have any compile error but after running it does not recognize any parent theme. for example this is one of

```
D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml
Error:(62, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(20, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(22, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(24, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(26, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(28, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(30, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(32, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(34, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(36, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(38, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(40, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(42, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(60, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(46, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(48, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(50, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(52, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(54, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(56, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(58, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\freetime\codes\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
```

I'm so confused and i have this problem for a long time and can not solve it. what should i do?

Comment: testing this app in v2.3 emulator or higher?

Answer (score 0):

Set your Project Build target to API level 21. Then rebuild your project.

Comment: I want to execute my app in android before 2.3.3 .does changing build target ignore this compatibility?

Comment: Do you have latest build target?

Comment: sorry i'm new in android!is build target the same as Project language level in project structure?

Comment: To support values-v21, Your Build Target should be 5.0. Go to File -> "Project Structure"

Under Platform Settings -> SDKs you can see android sdk path, classpath and build target.

Update your sdk first with latest build target using sdk manager.

Comment: ok,i checked it. i have the last version of sdk and i do what you said.but still it has the same errors

Comment: post your settings in build.gradle  file

Comment: i do not have this file in my project

Comment: And check these answers. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431676/appcompat-v721-0-0-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr-andro). and [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml)

Comment: i did what they said and it work fine but the main problem still does not solve.i want to run my app in device with android 2.3.3 . in these devices the action bar does not shown