# How to get elements from Android Design Support Library into the GUI builder in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to design a GUI using the Android GUI builder in Eclipse. I want to use the `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`, but I don't see it in the palette view.

- I have already imported the **appcompat_v7 library** into the workspace as a project and referenced to it from my Android project;
- I have already imported the **design support library** into the workspace as a project and referenced to it from my Android project;
- I've set the build path to Android API level 23 (the newest at the moment) to prevent errors like [*No resource found...*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml) from being issued;
- I've cleaned all my projects;
- I've restarted Eclipse.

How can I make sure the `TextInputLayout` is available in the palette view?

Comment: Last I knew, Eclipse didn't support any widgets from libraries, whether those are official support libraries or not. Of course, I haven't touched Eclipse in quite some time.

Comment: You can't, I would stay away from the Eclipse GUI builder it'll give you more issues than it's worth. Why don't you just use `XML` view?

Comment: Okay... And what about Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to get library widgets to work (though widgets from the project itself do show up – though they don't always work, seems to depend on the widget).

However, there is a workaround: if you add them to the XML file, you can view and edit them in the visual editor. You can add the widget entirely by hand, or find its "native" ancestor: According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html), `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` extends `LinearLayout`, therefore simply drop a `LinearLayout` into your layout, then go to the XML and change

```
<LinearLayout ... />
```

to

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout ... />
```

Eclipse may add a `xmlns:app` attribute to your top layout (and then complain about it being invalid). Simply change its contents to

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Whenever you edit attributes, Eclipse will add another `xmlns:app1` attribute – simply delete it and change your widget's `app1:*` attributes to `app:*`.

The whole thing is a bit buggy and requires manual intervention, but works eventually.