# I am getting an error when i add a dependencies

Tags: android

When an i add a dependencies for Google Play Services

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.adeel.facialimagedetection"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8+'
}
```

And At the time i sync the project i am getting an execution Error

```
C:\Users\Adeel\AndroidStudioProjects\FacialImageDetection\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(208) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(211) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(221) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(228) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(174) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(45) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(47) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(50) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(163) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(165) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(167) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(169) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(172) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(177) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(178) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(179) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(180) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(181) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(183) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(187) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(189) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(197) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(198) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(200) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(210) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(212) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(217) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(219) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
C:\Users\Adeel\AndroidStudioProjects\FacialImageDetection\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\22.2.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(77, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(126, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(129, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(129, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(129, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(129, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(129, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(129, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(129, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(178, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(211, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(222, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(257, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(257, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(257, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(257, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(257, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(257, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(257, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(267, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(267, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(267, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(267, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(267, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(267, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(267, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Adeel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Can anyone help me in changing or adding some other dependency ... 
I am using an APK 19 for building the project and i have to do this for face detection 
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml

Comment: change your compile sdk version to 21

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26457138/5028508