# After importing project, not able to run it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to learn android development from Udacity but having some problems importing project.
In the task there is a half ready project is given as a resource to start with which is about creating language translating app code. But when I am trying to compile the project it comes up with following errors:

Error:(18, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\Rushi\Downloads\ud839_Miwok-Starter-code\ud839_Miwok-Starter-code\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Error:(19, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\Rushi\Downloads\ud839_Miwok-Starter-code\ud839_Miwok-Starter-code\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.

Error:(20, -1) android-apt-compiler: [main] C:\Users\Rushi\Downloads\ud839_Miwok-Starter-code\ud839_Miwok-Starter-code\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.

I thought that It lacks any kind of packages or something so tried to update the Android Studio to the latest version but it didn't work.

I have checked that the attribute colorPrimaryDark and colorPrimary references to the correct resource which they do.

Comment: Does doing a clean help? (goto Build -> Clean project)

Comment: @jak10h code clean up doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add to your app's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```

and also try this: `Build->Rebuild Project`, `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

If the problem doesn't go away, please, post your `build.gradle` and `colors.xml` files.

Comment: my android studio doesn't have  rebuild option under build section.

Comment: I also tried to restart the project but it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either increase the `compileSdkVersion` or `buildToolsVersion` in your `app/build.gradle` file.

Or you have to use higher version numbers for external dependencies libraries like the AppCompat or support-v7. For example, changing `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'` to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`.

Note that `Theme.AppCompat` comes from the support library.

Source: [AppCompat v7 r21 returning error in values.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457096/appcompat-v7-r21-returning-error-in-values-xml)

Comment: How can I increase compileSdkVersion or buildToolsVersion. I am totally new to android studio

Comment: @RushiPatel Please see https://www.raywenderlich.com/120177/beginning-android-development-tutorial-installing-android-studio and https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html