# Android Support Library with nVidia AndroidWorks

Tags: android, nvidia, tegra

On the feature list for Android Works (https://developer.nvidia.com/AndroidWorks), the Android Support Library is included. however, I cannot figure out how to link it. Most likely, I need to put com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1 or something similar somewhere in Visual Studio's build settings. I know that it is not linked because

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

fails with "package does not exist."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

Create the following file: C:\ProjectName\ProjectName\nsight_tegra_build_overrides.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<project name="ProjectName" Basedir="C:\ProjectName\ProjectName\">
    <property name="android.library.reference.1" value = "../../NVPACK/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat"  />
</project>
```

The overrides file adds this line to nsight_tegra_build.xml when it is generated. The path for android.library.reference.1 must be a relative path. See [How to define v7 appcompat dependency correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209041/how-to-define-v7-appcompat-dependency-correctly). Run:

```
c:\NVPACK\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin>android update project -p c:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\
```

Change `target=android-19` to `target=android-21` in C:\NVPACK\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\project.properties. After that, it should be buildable from within Visual Studio.